# How do we rename a file with the last day of previous month in Windows batch files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I need to program a batch that renames an Excel file with the date of the last day of the previous month in DDMMYYY format.
I have an example of code renaming using the current date.

```
ren example.xls example_%DATE:/=%.xls
```

Is there a method to do the same with the last day of the previous month?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get some help from powershell:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Date -Day 1 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddSeconds(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"') DO (
   ren "example.xls" "%%i.xls"
)
```

The date format can be changed as per your needs at the end of the `powershell` string which is currently `("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: @lit, yes, I am aware thanks. Posted from my phone and did not still have time to look at formatting. Will change a bit later at my PC. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to use a `for` loop if you're happy with using PowerShell. You could just do it in one line:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "Rename-Item -Path \".\example.xls\" -NewName \"$(((Get-Date -Day 1).AddDays(-1)).ToString('ddMMyyyy')).xls\""
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really simple when you use the right formula:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A "M=1%%b-100,a=^!(M-1),Y=%%c-a,M+=12*a-1,D=30+((M+(M-8>>31)+1)&1)-^!(M-2)*(2-^!(Y%%4)),M+=100"
)
ren example.xls example_%D%%M:~1%%Y%.xls
```

If you are not using Delayed Expansion, remove the `^` caret from the three `!` operators.

Tip: get the time this pure Batch solution takes and compare it vs. the PowerShell one...

Comment: Nice solution, but at 2100-03-dd it fails

Comment: @jeb: Just change `(2-^!(Y%%4))` by `(2-^!(Y%%4)*^!(Y%%400))` so it also works in 79 years!  **`;)`**

Comment: The correction should be `(2-^!(Y%%4)*^!(Y%%100))` in 2100 the 100 years rule matches the next 400 years rule is 2400, but it's a bit unrealistic for me to assume to see the year 2100 :-)

Comment: @jeb: The right correction for years 2100, 2200 and 2300 is: `(2-^!(Y%%4)*^!^!(Y%%100))` and to also fix 2400, use: `(2-^!(Y%%4)*^!^!(Y%%100)-^!(Y%%400))`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to calculate that date.

1. Start with the current date (20.12.2021)
2. change the current day to 1 (1.12.2021)
3. convert this date to a julian day (2459550)
4. subtract 1 day (2459549)
5. convert it back to a gregorian date (30.11.2021)

Comment: Not necessarily. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70435823/778560)...